# Producer and Consumer not decoupled

Tags: rabbitmq

From my reading around rabbitmq and AMQP, most exchanges, queues and bindings are done by the application e.g.

```
App1(Producer) declares exchange1
App2(Consumer) declares queue1 and binds to exchange1
```

I have seen then in order not to have missing messages that both should declare additional config, so now would be:

```
App1(Producer) declares exchange1, declares queue1 and binds to exchange1
App2(Consumer) declares exchange1, declares queue1 and binds to exchange1
```

Now the Producer App needs to know details it never needed to known.
Is this acceptable? It feels wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cosumer to be able to bind an exchange to a queue he wants to consume messages from, the exchange must exist and have the expected type (fanout, direct, topic) and configuration.

Consider a situation where the consumer would rely on the exchange being created by somebody else. If he would just create the queue and then try to bind it to the missing exchange, he would get an error.

In a scenario where specificicly configured things (exchange, queue, binding) must exist before a consumer can do his part of the setup, you have three options:

1. Configure the required things by a third party that is guaranteed to finish before producers and consumers run from application code.
2. Configure the required things by the producer or the consumer and make sure this part of the application code is run first.
3. Let the producer and the consumer perform identical steps to configure the required things. This makes the order in which the different parts of the application code are executed irrelevant.

The third option works if the configuration steps are identical in all aspects. For example, RabbitMQ accepts the repeated creation of an exchange, if this configuration always is identical. It throws an error, if an existing exchange is configured again with differing configuration.

I would say the the third option is advisiable for a scenario where the application code does the setup. It feels right to me.